# Primefaces Multiple Value autocomplete

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces autocomlete force selection to search over accounts by name

**JSF Component**

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{journal.journal.debit}"
                completeMethod="#{account.completeAccount}" 
                var="var" itemLabel="#{var.name}" itemValue="#{var}"
                forceSelection="true" immediate="false" required="true">
```

**Bean Method:**

```
public List<Account> completeAccount(String query) {
    List<Account> allAccounts = service.get(Account.class);
    List<Account> filteredAccounts = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < allAccounts.size(); i++) {
        Account foundAccount = allAccounts.get(i);
        if (foundAccount.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
            filteredAccounts.add(foundAccount);
        }
    }
    return filteredAccounts;
}
```

this works fine, now if I want to change the search to search also for account number in the query value. I have used the following:

```
if (foundAccount.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()) || foundAccount.getNumber() == Integer.parseInt(query)) {
            filteredAccounts.add(foundAccount);
        }
```

but then, the filter is only returning searching for the number and ignoring name search. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that what Deepak was trying to say is that what you're doing is perfectly valid, and not an issue with primefaces rather something wrong with your condition. And indeed, the most obvious thing is that there is no `Integer.parseInteger(String s)` method, at least no in `java.lang.Integer`.

If this is a typo of some sort, and if you're working with *Integer* objects (not the *int* primitives) , make sure that you're comparing them by using `.equals` method. Comparing Integers by `==` will work only in the range from -128 - 127, outside of that range it will compare references.

Hope it helps

Comment: It was a typo and I have edited my code `.getNumber()` will return `int` and not `Integer` therefore I used `==` instead of `.equals`. after implementing the second condition the second condition is performed and the first condition is ignored.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
if (
     (foundAccount.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
     ||
     (foundAccount.getNumber() == Integer.parseInteger(query))
   )
{
   filteredAccounts.add(foundAccount);
}
```